# iPhone 5 iOS7 no sound only vibrates when ringing?

Tags: audio, ios, iphone, call

Here is what I tried...

1. `Do Not Disturb` is off
2. In `Settings -> Sounds`, `Vibrate on Ring` is off and `Vibrate on Silent` is off
3. The switch on the side is set to silver not red.
4. The music will play over the headphones and over the speaker.
5. The keyboard click sound will play over the headphones and over the speaker.
6. I looked in `Settings -> Accessibility` and there doesn't seem to be anything in there (however whenever I got the phone the zoom was turned on)

I don't know what else there is to try, but it doesn't play the ring tone when the phone rings.

Comment: I think you indirectly answered the question, but when you go to Settings.app -> Sounds -> Ringtone, does the ringtone you have selected play as expected when you tap it?

Comment: Yes it does play the sounds when I tap the ringtone.  But it still does not ring when I call it.

Comment: And restarting the iPhone doesn't improve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is fixed in the latest iOS 7 update.

Comment: Sorry we couldn't help. I had a syncing issue that was cleared up by 7.1

Answer (score 8):

moving mine in and of the holster moved the ringer button to the off position accidently. Glad it was something that simple....but sure stumped me for a while.
the ringer button is the one above the volume buttons on the left side

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. This is what happened to me too.

Comment: I feel stupid:-) Same here...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my iphone 6 plus Im on ios 8.3. My phone would only vibrate no ringtone. My fix: Toggle the ringer button on the left side of my phone OFF and ON.

Additional settings (if it would help you):

Settings>Do Not Disturb>
Manual (Off)
Scheduled (Off)
Allow Calls From (Everyone)
Repeated Calls (On)

SILENCE>

Only while iPhone is locked (check)

****and****

Settings> Sounds>
Vibrate on Ting (on)
Vibrate on Silent (on)

RINGER AND ALERTS (set in the middle)

Change with Buttons (on)

SOUNDS AND VIBRATION PATTERNS
Ringtone (summit)
Text Tone (hello)
New Voicemail (Tri-tone)
New Mail (Ripples)
Sent Mail (Popcorn)
Tweet (keys)
Facebook Post (swish)
Calendar Alerts ( Hello)
Reminder Alerts (Chord)
AirDrop (pulse)

Lock sounds (off)
Keyboard clicks (off)

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: I love the way we keep having to fix this again with every update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hold on home and lock button for 10 second,
Mine would vibrate for incoming calls but would not ring. This fixed mine right away.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ring/silent switch on the left side of the iPhone 5s, (right side for iPhone 6), just above the sound up and down arrows.  Slide it up, and that should turn your ringer back on, you should be able to hear your phone ring.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - everything looked right in settings but my iphone5 still only vibrated.  The ring tone that I had it set to indeed had stopped working when I tested it, so I switched to another ring tone and it works.

Answer (score -1):

For iPhone 6plus:
- locate volume control on left side of phone
- find small silver switch just above that
- use your fingernail to switch it in the direction of your screen. 
- test to see if your phone ringer is working

Comment: OP states that the switch is "on" on his phone and that they have an iPhone 5. Moreover, the switch hasn't changed in functionality or location on any iPhone.

Answer (score -2):

Power volume flex cable is damaged, change it

Comment: The accepted answer indicates this isn't the case. Want to remove this? It's wrong and will attract down votes.